# Import own C module in a Python virtualenv

Tags: python, c, import, hyperlink, virtualenv

I try to import C code into a Python script working in a virtualenv. I manage to link my C code with Python installing a setup.py into python. But when I am in my virtualenv, I can't find my module, and I don't know how to install it with pip install..

I explain my situation. I have a foo.c and a setup.py associated to foo.c. I can install it in python without problem like this :

```
$sudo python2.7 setup.py install
```

and then in python2.7 :

```
$python2.7
>>>import foo
>>>foo.hello()
'hello word'
>>>
```

it works fine.

However, in my virtualenv (in which there are several module installed),

```
source my_v_env/bin/activate

(my_v_env)$python2.7
>>>import foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named foo
>>>
```

My foo module is not found. I know it is possible to install module with "pip install {module}" but in my case I don't know how to install this foo module..

Thank you for your answers,

PR.

Comment: It would be helpful to post your answer as an answer, and then mark it solved.

Answer (score 0):

I naively tried to compress my setup.py and foo.c into a foo.tar.gz and to execute

```
(my_v_env)$pip install foo.tar.gz
```

and it works well !

Maybe it will help other people :-)

Note (docs.python.org/2/extending/building.html) that the command

```
$python setup.py sdist
```

create a tar.gz you can install with pip by the same way..